# Enviar checkbox como arreglo en ajax y procesarlo codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Mi problema es que al enviar el arreglo con los checkboxs seleccionados, en mi controlador me recibe la variable vacia.
Por ejemplo tengo:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='valores[]' value='1' />
<input type='checkbox' name='valores[]' value='2' />
<input type='checkbox' name='valores[]' value='3' />
<input type='checkbox' name='valores[]' value='4' />
```

y para enviarlo por ajax hago lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
        url:$("form").attr("action"),
        type: $("form").attr("method"),
        data:$("form").serialize(),
success:function(respuesta)
        {
        alert('Perfil creado con éxito');
        }
```

y en mi controlador lo recibo de la siguiente manera:

```
$ids = $this->input->post('valores');
```

He sacado 'valores' en un alert y me imprime algo como esto:
valores%5B%5D=1&valores%5B%5D=2

Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal, o como puedo recibir estos datos de forma adecuada para procesarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar `$.param(data)` para enviar los datos del formulario.